# socket.gethostbyname(host_name) working in terminal but not working in Django?

Tags: python, django, sockets, ubuntu, networking

I am trying to find out my ip using `socket` library in my `Django` project using this script.

```
import socket
host_name = socket.gethostname()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
```

I get this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Error is pointing to line `ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)`.

But, I do not get this error while running this same script in terminal.

```
>>> import socket
>>> hostname = socket.gethostname()
>>> ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
>>> 
>>> ip
'192.168.191.5'
```

This is my `/etc/hosts`

```
#127.0.0.1      localhost
#127.0.1.1      softcell-Latitude-3510

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have commented out everything because I want socket to return the System IP.

Why is this not working in Django but giving correct output in Terminal?

Comment: what's your result of `print(hostname)` ?

Comment: softcell-Latitude-3510